# how to access ascx custom control property from masterpage.master.cs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, custom-controls

I have this following property in my custom user control:

```
public string selectedtab 
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["AdminCurrentNavID"] != null)
                {
                    return ViewState["AdminCurrentNavID"].ToString();
                }
                else {
                    isfirstload = true;
                    return null;                
                }
            }

            set { ViewState["AdminCurrentNavID"] = value; }
        }
```

I am setting the value of it on my Page_Load() in ascx control. What i need to do is that after setting the value of this property I need to access it from masterpage.cs in code behind. you can see how currently I am trying to do in below code, but the issue is that I am not able to get the value i thing it is because the masterpage's Page_Load() rendering before the ascx control so I thats why I am getting null value, please help, thanks.

**masterpage.cs:**

```
usercontrols.mainmenu adminmenu = (usercontrols.mainmenu)LoadControl("~/mymenupath.ascx");
lbmsg.Text = adminmenu.selectedtab;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using Delegate, you can see in the link below.

http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/Return-value-from-user-control-in-ASP-NET-and-C-Sharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you call LoadControl in your master page, you are actually creating a new instance of your user control, not accessing the one you have somewhere in your site.

When you declare the User Control in your page you should have given it an id. You could access the property with something like `((usercontrols.mainmenu)MyUserControlId).selectedtab`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I do not have an ID because i use placeholder then I do


placeholderId.Controls.Add(adminmenu);

Comment: you can do placeholderId.FindControl("myUserControlId") instead, but make sure you assign an id to the user control before adding it to the placeholder.

Comment: I don't have an ID also I am not sure if you exactly understand what I am trying to do, because I cant put any ID to the ascx control to do FindControl I am loading in code, but thank you  very much for your help, I found the exact solution in my answer below you see I posted.